# how to change promise to json in nextjs 12?

Tags: next.js

how to fiks error code :

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM3S6.png)

l want to fetching api open source but l cant to use that because l dont know why, that code always to be promise.

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.